# Auto edit MySQL data after a given time

Tags: mysql, laravel

We have a form which is stored in draft mode. That means editing any data or deleting the entire form is possible. The beginning to end process is as follows

- When a person tries to submit the form for the first time, that is stored in draft. (the **isDraft** column is set to 0)
- The user is redirected to another page where s/he can view the Form id (a generated number), name, a few other details and Edit/Delete options.
- The user can click edit button to edit anything, or even delete the form.
- However this will be allowed till a given date (say 15 days from the first submission date). Once that date is passed, the form can no longer be edited or deleted. In case the form isn't deleted, the **isDraft** column is set to 1.

Thousands of people can submit the form . So ,it is not possible to do it manually.

**Our project is done using Laravel v6.2, but I want a general idea as well .**

I can use a **trait** or **ajax** on the **master** page, but that is too risky and also, server inaccessibility can delay the process, and some users may get an advantage.

How to do it?

If there is no concrete answer, but rather **only** discussion , I will remove this post

Comment: A combination of laravel scheduling and Server cron job can easily handle your matter at hand. I have a job portal online that leverages Laravel Scheduling and Cpanel Cron Job that deletes all the outdated jobs exactly at midnight every night. Here is docs for laravel scheduling: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/scheduling

Comment: @AhmadKarimi What if I am to call a controller action automatically?

Comment: Via Scheduling, you can make laravel commands to actually call a controller function to do the job for you.

Comment: @AhmadKarimi okay. Please consider posting it as an answer for my reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just store the date (time component depends on how accurate you want to be when you check the 15 day interval) when the form is created as draft.

When a user wants to edit it (display the edit form) or save an edit, compare the current date (and time) with the stored creation date + 15 days. If the current date is less than the creation date + 15 days, then allow the display of the edit form or save the form, otherwise display an error message.

Comment: Asish, Actually I would advise this approach since it doesn't make your logic complicated. Only to add to @Shadow 's suggestion, When the user attempts to update the post, first check if collumn isDraft is set to 1 to prevent user from editing it. If the isDraft is still 0, then check if the date is passed 15 days, then return to user an notification and also immediately change the post's column isDraft to 1.

Comment: I can even right you the method controller to handle this way, but I am sure you can handle it.

Comment: @AhmadKarimi no need for that isdarft column at all, create date + 15 days is the same, based on the description.

Comment: Then your job becomes much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand it correctly, but I think you like to update the updated_at timestamp automatically. You can run through the Eloquent Models by create a command and just call the save Method on them.

$model->save()